# Connecting two data sources. Plot Pie Charts on Map. Asterisks for a part of data. '*'

Tags: data-visualization, tableau-api

Here is my question: 
I am getting asterisks for 90% of my data items when I connect 2 data sources.

**The strange part is that 10% of the data is still displayed correctly!**

Also this problem is encountered **only in Map - mode**!

---

**FIRST DATA SOURCE:**

```
LOCATION_NAME           ZIP
_____________         _________
 Name_1                 zip_1
 Name_2                 zip_1
 Name_3                 zip_2  
 Name_4                 zip_3
 Name_5                 zip_3
 Name_6                 zip_4
 Name_7                 zip_3
 Name_8                 zip_5
  ...                    ...
```

---

**SECOND DATA SOURCE:**

```
LOCATION_NAME            ROOM             ALERT_COUNT
_____________         _________          ____________
  Name_1                 #1                  1
  Name_1                 #2                  0
  Name_2            'Main Office'            0
  Name_2               'Office'              2
  Name_2              'Kitchen'              1
  Name_3               'Office1'             1 
  Name_4                  3                  5
  Name_4                 #1                  3
  Name_5              'Storage'              0
   ...                    ...               ...
```

---

**QUESTION**:

I would like to count the alerts for every room for every location and plot 
them on the map as pie charts.

In edit relationships I connected LOCATION_NAME of the first data source with the second.
Used count(Alert_count) and dragged and dropped it to size.
Also I dragged and dropped LOCATION_NAME to marks.

At that point I saw a bunch of different size circles on the map that represent ALERT_COUNT for a specific LOCATION_NAME.

Then I decided to make them pie charts. I dragged and dropped ROOM to "Color"
and this is what I saw in the color legend:

[*red*] Null

[*green*] #1

[*blue*] 'Storage'

[*yellow*]  '*'

So a part of my data is used correctly and a part is *.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure how data blending work in details in Tableau (but now got curious and will investigate), but I've had some trouble with this feature when the secondary source has more than 1 match for each key. Probably data blending is not like a SQL join and has its limitations. For your case, I'm not sure if it's possible (and I don't have my Tableau right now, will check tomorrow) but you can try making your second data source the primary. That way you'll not have the * problem, but I'm not sure the maps will work. Need to test

Comment: Data blending is a useful, but advanced and somewhat complicated feature. If you can use a server side join instead, you usually are better off performance-wise. A loose "almost correct" way to think of blending is as a left join that is performed on the client side upon the *aggregated* results that are supplied by the primary and secondary data sources. So it's great for comparing values in one source, say a spreadsheet, with related values in another source, say a database. There are other good uses, including self-blends. But if you have tables on the same server, prefer joins to blends.